# Android Espresso AppNotIdleException with Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, android-espresso

When I add the Facebook SDK and the applicationId in the manifest the Espresso tests do not work
If there are multiple test methods in the class the error only occurs on the first test

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
```

Results in AppNotIdleException exception

```
E/TestRunner: androidx.test.espresso.AppNotIdleException: Looped for 2 iterations over 60 SECONDS. The following Idle Conditions failed .
        at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1538)
        at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:94)
        at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:57)
        at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:316)
        at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.desugaredPerform(ViewInteraction.java:177)
        at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:118)
```

If I remove the `com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId` from manifest the tests run normally

Android test versions:

```
ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
        koin_version = '2.0.0-rc-2'
        nav_version = '2.0.0'
        arch_version = '2.0.1'
        retrofit_version = '2.5.0'
        lifecycle_version = '2.0.0'
        glide_version = '4.9.0'
        espresso_version = '3.1.1'
    }
```

```
//  Facebook
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.42.0'

// Android test
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$lifecycle_version"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espresso_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$espresso_version"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation "org.koin:koin-test:$koin_version"
    androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:2.25.0"
    androidTestImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.14.1'

    // Unit test
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation "androidx.test:core:1.1.0"
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$lifecycle_version"
    testImplementation "org.koin:koin-test:$koin_version"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.27.0"
    testImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.14.1'
```

Comment: I am running into the same issue, have you found the solution?

Comment: I'm going through something similar. Even though I cannot remove the imports (otherwise my Activity won't work and the test won't run), I debug the test and see a worker thread running with a few "GraphRequest {com.facebook}" calls in it, and the test also fails with an AppNotIdleException exception.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and fixed it by putting this in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application ...>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.AutoInitEnabled" android:value="false"/>
</application>
```

Additional Info: [FB GDPR Compliance](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/gdpr-compliance/)

Comment: I was getting different error messages depending on the emulator but this fixed the issue I was having with `onView` (hanging until timeout). Thanks!